# How can i get the child div s and set position with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div id="parent">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
    <div>c</div>
</div>
```

I have used fixed positioning. So how can get all the child elements in the parent div with jquery. first child's `top:100px` and second child's `top:200px` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $('#parent div').each(function(index){
   $(this).css({ top: (100*(index+1))+'px' });
  })
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DSxW5/)**

Comment: damn you! no doubt I was first

Comment: @pythonian29033 .. yh but this is the simplest answer .. isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `css` method's callback function:

```
$('#parent > div').css('top', function(i) {
   return ++i * 100 + 'px'; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `.children()` method to loop through the children;

```
$("#parent").children().each(function(index){
   var top = (index + 1) * 100;
   $(this).attr("style", "top:" + top + "px");
});
```